# Handle Double Tap Globally WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

So I'm just doing tests to my project, and realized that if you have a link (for example navigation service), it takes both taps and double taps. This means if I have a button that goes to another page within the app, unless I don't handle the double tap, the app will crash.

So if I have this:

```
<toolkit:HubTile Name="XXX"
      Message="XXXYYY" Source="ZZZ" 
      Title="XYZ" Tap="XYZ_Tap"/>
```

If anyone double taps this tile, the app will crash. So instead I have to add the

```
DoubleTap="XYZ_DoubleTap"
```

property. But this can get both tiring and seems unnecessary. So is there a way to handle ALL double taps globally? Then if I want to actually implement it somewhere, just override it? Thanks :)

Edit: The "Global" event handler for DoubleTap is simple to do nothing. This way I don't have to rewrite it for each link or button. And an exception won't be thrown each time an none handled DoubleTap is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom Control that inherits from `HubTile` and set the `DoubleTap` event to do nothing in that class.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing now. I just wish there was something more for every single DoubleTap rather than specific to each element. Thanks though, since your answer was the closest to what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The crash is most likely occurring because an exception was thrown on the second "tap".  Something along the lines of "Navigation is not allowed when the task is not in the foreground."

I guess putting an empty event handler for DoubleTap will work, as it recognizes the double tap event and does nothing.  Another approach, which probably should be done anyway, is to wrap the navigation call in a try/catch block to catch the exception thrown by the second tap.

But to address your specific question, what sort of global handling of a double tap were you envisioning other than doing nothing?

Comment: Well I know why the app was crashing, and also know why the exception. That is why I am addressing it. But putting an empty DoubleTap event handler for each and every button, link or what not seems unnecessary.

Comment: So the global handler that takes care of what double tap does, and that is nothing. This way I don't have to rewrite the DoubleTap event handler for each link.

Comment: Unfortunately, event handlers are restricted to be instance members of the specific class, so I don't think you will be able to do this.  I still think the easier solution is to just catch the exception in a try/catch.  See link for event requirements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221357%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: I though Try-Catch blocks in this situation would be a bad idea. We know why the exception is being thrown, it better be handled, right? I think for now I'll just use Olivier's solutions.

Comment: It depends on how you look at it and what you want the behavior to be. If the user "double-taps" or accidentally hits the button more than once, do you want it to do nothing?  If so, then implementing a DoubleTap event handler achieves that.  If you want the double tap to register similar to a single tap, then using the try/catch will catch the unwanted exception from the second tap, but the user will still navigate.  In general though, since there is the possibility of an exception, it seems safer to have try/catch.  Just my two cents.

Comment: Just found this link which discusses this issue and options to deal with it: http://nikovrdoljak.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/how-to-crash-other-wp7-applications/